# How to fix first two columns and Header of Bootstrap RWD Table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap table. I can freeze the second column while scroll horizontal.

My code:

```css
.table>thead:first-child>tr:first-child>th:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #D4D4D4;
  width: 80px;
  /*height: 100%;*/
}

.table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #D4D4D4;
  width: 80px;
  /*height: 100%;*/
}

.table>thead:first-child>tr:first-child>th:nth-child(3) {
  padding-left: 100px;
}

.table>tbody>tr>td:nth-child(3) {
  padding-left: 100px !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebITD</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Table Bootstrap</h2>
  <p>The .table-responsive class creates a responsive table which will scroll horizontally on small devices (under 768px). When viewing on anything larger than 768px wide, there is no difference:</p>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>City</th>
          <th>Country</th>
          <th>Country2</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>8</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>10</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>11</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>12</td>
          <td>Anna</td>
          <td>Pitt</td>
          <td>35</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>USA</td>
          <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chengct3/qxw10njb/)

If I want to freeze first two columns (# and Firstname) and the table header while scrolling. How can I modify? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the same way, just add the indent:

```
        .table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) {
            position: absolute;
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: #D4D4D4;
            width:40px;
            /*height: 100%;*/
        }

        .table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) {
            position: absolute;
            display: inline-block;
            background-color: #D4D4D4;
            width:80px;
            left:40px;
            /*height: 100%;*/
        }
```

Comment: After I add  td:nth-child(1),  first column is disappear,  I don't know why?

Comment: don't forget to add 'left:40px' for ':nth-child(2)'